# MKNetworkKit example calling Amazon S3

Tags: ios5, amazon-s3, mknetworkkit

Is there a good example of how to use MKNetworkKit with S3?  I used to use Asi but switching to MKNetworkKit and I haven't found anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MKNetworkKit has an experimental branch "s3" that talks to Amazon server. But I'm not officially supporting it yet. Wait for a couple of weeks or so.

Comment: Mugunth, is this feature still is in progress? Do you have plans on releasing new version of your great library with this feature?)